# Angular material table, scrollbar appears on the whole page

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a page with a `header`, `footer` and a `mat-tab` control with a `mat-table` in each tab.
When the `mat-table` gets populated, and it exceeds the available `height`, instead of applying a `scrollbar` only on the `mat-table`, it pushes the `footer` down and I get a `scrollbar` on the whole page.

How could I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fixed height in mat-tab-group like this:

```
mat-tab-group {
  height: 200px;
}
```

The height needs to be limited to a specific number of pixels for this to happen.

Check [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jakbce-4jeqlu?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html) for a working example.

I would need to see your own code for specific implementation and help.

Comment: So there is no way to limit it to 100% of the current display area? I am using css-grid and I have a `grid-template-rows: 5fr 30fr 5fr;` for the `header`, `mat-tab` and `footer`.

Comment: Yes there is use `height: calc(100vh - 75px);` where in that case empty space is reduce by `75px` you can change it to you display @hdoradu